# Perl: array reference versus anonymous array

Tags: arrays, perl

This may be a silly question... The following code outputs the contents of `@arrayref` and `@arraycont` respectively. Note the difference between them and the way the values of them are assigned. I know what the anonymous array does, but can anybody explain why there is a difference?

Thank you very much.

```
@arrayref = ();
@array = qw(1 2 3 4);
$arrayref[0] = \@array;
@array = qw(5 6 7 8);
$arrayref[1] = \@array;
print join "\t", @{$arrayref[0]}, "\n";
print join "\t", @{$arrayref[1]}, "\n";

@arraycont = ();
@array = qw(1 2 3 4);
$arraycont[0] = [@array];
@array = qw(5 6 7 8);
$arraycont[1] = [@array];
print join "\t", @{$arraycont[0]}, "\n";
print join "\t", @{$arraycont[1]}, "\n";
```

outputs

```
5   6   7   8   
5   6   7   8   
1   2   3   4   
5   6   7   8
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This creates a *shallow* copy of the array:

`$arraycont[0] = [@array];`

Whereas this just creates a reference to it:

`$arrayref[0] = \@array;`

Since you later modify the array:

`@array = qw(5 6 7 8);`

`arrayref` still points to the same array location in memory, and so when dereferenced in the print statements it prints the current array values `5 6 7 8`.

Comment: A *shallow* copy, if `@array` contained references then `[@array]` would contain those same references. The deep/shallow difference doesn't apply in this case but I thought it was worth mentioning anyway.

Answer (score 3):

The first block stores the address of **@array**. REferences are like **'live streaming'**, you get current status.
So if you create a reference to **@array, like \@array,** when you de-reference it you will always get what **@array** points at the moment of de-reference.
When you de-refer **@array** was having **(5 6 7 8)**

When you do **[@array]** its like recording the **live streaming** into your disk. So when you (re)play the recorded content you get what was
streamed at the time of recording. So when you refer **$arraycont[0]** you get what **@array** was having at the time of copying that is
**(1 2 3 4)**

Answer (score 0):

You made stored references to a single array in both `$arrayref[0]` and `$arrayref[1]`. You 
should have used different arrays.

```
my @refs;

my @array1 = qw(1 2 3 4);
push @refs, \@array1;

my @array2 = qw(5 6 7 8);
push @refs, \@array2;
```

In practice, `my` is executed in each pass of a loop, creating a new array each time.

```
my @refs;
while ( my @row = get() ) {
   push @refs, \@row;
}
```

In rare occasions where you have to clone an array, you can use:

```
use Storable qw( dclone );

push @refs, [ @row ];       # Shallow clone
push @refs, dclone(\@row);  # Deep clone
```